# javascript error reading from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this segment of code that keeps throwing an error onclick. I have searched but have found nothing close to this type of code causing this error.  Mostly it was issue in `ajax` calls.  This is not an ajax call.  Dev tools is telling me that it is happening on this line of code

```
<html>
```

I feel that is not really telling the whole story.  error is -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Here is the code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
        data-toggle="popover"
        data-container="body" 
        data-placement="right"  
        data-trigger="focus" 
        data-content="<i class='fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg'></i> <a href='#contact' id='share-email' onclick='scrollElement('#contact')'>info@h3webelements.com</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-phone fa-lg'></i> 405.456.9447<br>
            <i class='fa fa-globe fa-lg'></i><a href='#footer' onclick='scrollElement('#footer')'> Warr Acres, Oklahoma</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg'></i><a href='http://www.twitter.com/h3webelements' target='_blank'> @H3WebElements</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-facebook-official fa-lg'></i><a href='https://www.facebook.com/H3WebElements' target='_blank'> H3 Web Elements</a></br>"
        data-html="true">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
function scrollElement (target) {
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 1500);

 }
```

Please note that the `scrollElement` function works fine on other aspects of the page- such as the `navbar`.  I believe that the issue is in the `data-content` section of the link I am using as a popup on a fixed position element. I am forced to use single `'` quotes.  I have tried to escape the `\'` and used `\"` but that just ended up breaking everything.  This should function as to scroll to the element as my navbar does already, right now it just takes it directly to the selected element.

Thanks

Comment: Your `data-content` contains unescaped HTML; check the DOM to see what the browser makes of it - it probably ends the `<a` tag at the first `>` it finds.

Comment: wouldn't that cause the link to fail as well?

Comment: This `onclick='scrollElement('#contact')'` and this `onclick='scrollElement('#footer')'` seems to have bad quotes.

Comment: they are single quotes.  Its the only way I can get it to read correctly within the data-content attribute.

Comment: I think you would benefit greatly from the use of s JavaScript template. Perhaps http://underscorejs.org/#template.

Comment: typo (as in: this question was raised due to a typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed in the repeating single quotes:

```
onclick='scrollElement('#contact')'
```

Since this code is in an attribute value we can use HTML entities to escape
the quotes:

```
onclick=&quot;scrollElement('#contact')&quot;
```

Here's a working snippet. Note that only the email link in the popover has been corrected:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $( 'a' ).popover();
})

function scrollElement(target) {
  console.log("scrollElement", target);
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 1500);

 }
```

```css
#contact { position: relative;top:1000px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0);"
        data-toggle="popover"
        data-container="body" 
        data-placement="right"  
        data-trigger="focus" 
        data-content="<i class='fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg'></i> <a href='#contact' id='share-email' onclick=&quot;scrollElement('#contact')&quot;>info@h3webelements.com</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-phone fa-lg'></i> 405.456.9447<br>
            <i class='fa fa-globe fa-lg'></i><a href='#footer' onclick='scrollElement('#footer')'> Warr Acres, Oklahoma</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg'></i><a href='http://www.twitter.com/h3webelements' target='_blank'> @H3WebElements</a><br>
            <i class='fa fa-facebook-official fa-lg'></i><a href='https://www.facebook.com/H3WebElements' target='_blank'> H3 Web Elements</a></br>"
        data-html="true">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></a>

<div id='contact'>Test!</div>
```